# How do you access an parameter that is a type but no variable name?

Tags: c++

```
 insertItem (value_type )
 {
```

}

Most code functions i have used so far have been along the lines of
insertItem( value_type var) Which allows me to access the data through var. In these new functions the only thing inside the parathesis is a object type. I cant access an object by saying only its type.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask. Please collect your thoughts and pose your question in plain English with complete sentences. There's no way to understand the question as it's currently written.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't give it a name?

Comment: The functions in the header files do not use any variable names so i cant add to the functions in my implementation.

Comment: If you had a function  such as   array(const array&) ,
how would you access array& inside the function?

Comment: The header files only need the type info to declare them. The function definitions would have values as well. At least if they are used in the function. Sometimes just types are used (tagging) to differentiate functions that otherwise have the same arguments.

Comment: You don't need the forward declaration to give it a name in order for the definition to give it a name. I'd _recommend_ naming your parameters in both, but the language won't stop you if you do it in one and not the other.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah beware, you mixed that up. A **declaration** doesn't need names, a **definition** needs them if you intend to use them.

Comment: Not naming the parameter in the definition is a possible way to avoid warnings that the parameters are not used inside the function. You probably could also cast them to void (another way to avoid the warnings).

Comment: @Raildex  Thanks for pointing that out.  Not sure how I messed that up.  I've deleted the comment so I don't confuse anyone.

Answer (score 1):

> The functions in the header files do not use any variable names so i cant add to the functions in my implementation

No, you're wrong in saying the above statement. It is ***optional*** to name the parameters in the declarations(in header files) of the member functions. If you choose to not name the parameters in the declarations in header files, you can still name the parameter in the implementation files. One such example to get you started is shown below:

**header.h**

```
#pragma once 
#include <string>
class Name 
{
    public:
      //setter. Note here you can skip naming the parameter 
      void setName(std::string);
      
      //constructor 
      Name(std::string); //note that here also we can skip naming the parameter
      
    private:
        std::string name;
};
```

**source.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"

//note here in implementation we've named the member function parameter to be p
void Name::setName(std::string p)
{
    name = p;
}

//here in implementation we've named the constructor parameter to be p
Name::Name(std::string p): name(p)
{
    
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include "header.h"
int main()
{
    Name n1("anoop");//this uses constructor
    
    
    n1.setName("rana");//this uses the setter setName
    return 0;
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/A6XIbbisR)